# How much of Linux's recent TCP bufferbloat remediation also applies to SCTP?

Tags: networking, tcp

I am looking at rebuilding an existing communications sub-system within a shared-nothing cluster. The current message protocol is built on UDP but layers on reliable, in-order delivery and connections. To me this sounds like an ideal application for SCTP. In all likelihood I would use SOCK_SEQPACKET sockets.

A worry is bufferbloat. Recent kernels have rolled out multiple features to address bufferbloat (Byte Queue Limit, TCP Small Queue, fq_CoDel, etc). If I layer my reimplementation on SCTP which - if any - of these features will apply?

I am especially interested in TCP Small Queue (TSQ). [This LWN article](https://lwn.net/Articles/507065/) lists a sysctl knob and kernel APIs all starting with prefix tcp_. So does that mean TSQ truly applies only when using the TCP protocol? Or - given the large similarity between TCP and SCTP - is enough of the kernel's implementation of these stacks shared such that SCTP also partakes of TSQ?